# Filter MongoDB database and pull document into DataGridView with c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to filter a MongoDB database with the text stored inside a textbox. For example I would put "turtle" and all the entries that have the "Name" "turtle" will appear inside a datagridview.

Here is the code for the button which connects to the MongoDB database, gets the database name and the "users" collection and applies the filter of whatever is inside the textbox txtName.

```
    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");

        var database = client.GetDatabase("test");

        var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("users");

        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Name", txtName.Text);
    }
```

I'm not sure where to go next. I need to then bind all data into the datagridviews datasource to match the records that have the name turtle.

```
        dgvAll.DataSource = somevariable;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your data out of the database

```
var results = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

This will give you a list of objects that you an bind the same as you would another other collection.

You may want to look into strongly typing your models instead of using text queries. For example

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And when you query

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");

    var database = client.GetDatabase("test");

    var collection = database.GetCollection<MyModel>("users");

    var filter = Builders<MyModel>.Filter.Eq(x => x.SomeProperty == "SomeValue" && x.SomeOtherProperty == "SomeOtherValue");

    var results = collection.Find(filter).ToList();

    //Now you will have a list of MyModel objects in results - List<MyModel>
}
```

Once you have your collection (which ever way you go about getting it out of your database), you can just bind like this:

```
dgvAll.DataSource = results;
dgvAll.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the steps below...

1. query the DB

   ```
   var result = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
   ```

   the result will contain the list of data.
2. Deserialize `BsonDocument` to a POCO Class

   ```
   public class User
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public BsonObjectId _id { get; set; }
   }

   IEnumerable<User> allUsers = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<User>>(result);
   ```
3. You can bind the datasource now

   ```
   dgvAll.DataSource = allUsers;
   dgvAll.DataBind();
   ```

Your final code will look like as following...

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");

var database = client.GetDatabase("test");

var collection = database.GetCollection<MyModel>("users");

var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Name", txtName.Text);

var results = collection.Find(filter).ToList();

IEnumerable<User> allUsers = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<User>>(result);

dgvAll.DataSource = allUsers;
dgvAll.DataBind();
}
```

N.B: If you don't have `User` class, create it with necessary properties at first.